# How to implement HashMap for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocomplete, hashmap

Good day,

I have a following problem. In my Android application I have a list of entries in XML that contains bus stop name and ID. Those are put in a `HashMap` as IDs are unique, while stop names are not. The user interface of activity contains an `AutoCompleteTextView` and Spinner.

My objective is to populate auto-complete view with stop **names** and then pass the **ID** of selected stop to the other class that will display bus lines on that stop in spinner (via remote API).

So what the user will do is start typing stop name (e.g. Awesome Stop) and he will see two entries in auto-complete suggestions. Depending on which one he will select spinner will show different results.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to couple AutoCompleteTextView and HashMap. Auto-complete works well with `ArrayAdapter<String>` populated via `ArrayList<String>` but it's not terribly helpful because I can only get stop name back, and it's not very helpful since I actually need ID.

Many thanks for any tip.

Comment: Thank you. I am not too sure on my ability to do that kind of implementation, but I'll certainly try :)

Comment: I deleted my comment because it was wrong. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after a fair bit of time I figured it out, thanks to the tip from joaquin. It was indeed done by implementing custom adapter. And the `HashMap` was not very helpful in original goal. Below is the code, if someone stumbles upon a similar challenge.

Activity:

```
// Members
private long currentStopId;
protected Map<String,String> lineMap;
protected ArrayList<Stop> stopMap;
protected String previousUrl = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_line);

    // Get the list of stops from resourse XML
    getStopInformation();

    // Enable auto-complete
    stopInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.inputStopName);
    final HashMapAdapter adapter = new HashMapAdapter(this,R.layout.stop_list,stopMap);
    stopInput.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Add listener for auto-complete selection
    stopInput.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
            String selection = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // There we get the ID.
            currentStopId = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Adapter implementation:

```
public class StopAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private ArrayList<Stop> inputStopList;
private ArrayList<Stop> inputStopListClone;
private LayoutInflater lInflater;

/** Constructor */
public StopAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Stop> input) {
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inputStopList = input;
    inputStopListClone = inputStopList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return inputStopList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    Stop value = inputStopList.get(i);
    return value.getStopName();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    Stop stop = inputStopList.get(i);
    long value = Long.parseLong(stop.getStopCode());
    return value;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View myView = view;

    // R.layout.stop_list created in res/layout
    if(myView == null)
        myView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.stop_list,viewGroup, false);

    ((TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(getItem(i).toString());

    return myView;
}

/** Required by AutoCompleteTextView to filter suggestions. */
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                ArrayList<Stop> originalValues = new ArrayList<Stop>(inputStopList);
                filterResults.count = originalValues.size();
                filterResults.values = originalValues;
            }
            else {
                ArrayList<Stop> newValues = new ArrayList<Stop>();

                // Note the clone - original list gets stripped
                for(Stop stop : inputStopListClone)
                {
                    String lowercase = stop.getStopName().toLowerCase();
                    if(lowercase.startsWith(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase()))
                        newValues.add(stop);
                }

                filterResults.count = newValues.size();
                filterResults.values = newValues;
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

            if(filterResults != null && filterResults.count > 0) {
                inputStopList = (ArrayList<Stop>)filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are using `AutoCompleteTextView` instead of `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.

`MultiAutoCompleteTextView` is exactly what you need because it works exactly equal as `AutoCompleteTextView` with the difference that it can show more than one suggestion (if they exist) and lets the user choose only one of them.

Reference Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wMAv.png

For a nice example check out Android Developers: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: I'm not sure that I do need `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` here, since I need to select eventually just one stop, not multiple. As far as I understand the difference between two is the ability to continue auto-complete for multiple items. However, I need to get the ID of the selected item.

Comment: No, you are getting it wrong. `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` is exactly what you need because it lets you _see many_ suggestions and _choose only one_ of them.

Comment: But that's exactly what I have already. Maybe I didn't give a good example originally. There are two stops near my home, both called "Home stop". One goes direction FROM city center and has id=123, another one TO city center, id=124. As I start typing "Hom" in my `AutoCompleteTextView` I see two entries in the suggestions, both called "Home Stop". I can select either of them. But with `ArrayAdapter` it brings no value because I can't tell which one I selected: 123 or 124.

Comment: Well, then I go back to my first answer. You should use a CustomAdapter that implements BaseAdapter. It's pretty easy. I suggest you to try it: create new class (even an inner class) and set it to extend BaseAdapter. IDE will make you implement some methods. Implement them following some tutorial. There are tons of them, just use Google! Then, instead of using an ArrayAdapter, change it to CustomAdapter. (Replace ArrayAdapter for CustomAdapter in the adapter declaration)

Comment: Alright, thank you again. I'm looking into some tutorials on that and so far looks promising.